# Android: create dir fail

Tags: android, mkdir, android-external-storage

I'm unable to create a directory with this simple code:

```
public class ExternalStorage {
    private final String BACKUPS_DIR = "MyDir";

    public String createBackupDir() {
        if (!isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            Log.e("MyApp", "Storage not writable");
            return null;
        }

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + BACKUPS_DIR;

        File folder = new File(path);

        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists())
            success = folder.mkdirs();

        if (success)
            return path;

        Log.e("MyApp", "Backup Dir: creation failed");
        return null;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }
}
```

The return value of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is:

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

The log is:

```
MyApp   : Backup Dir: creation failed
```

Manifests permissions are:

```
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

mkdirs only returns false , i can't figure what is happen, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Manifests permissions are:

     <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: be aware that your log will everytime be executed, no matter if the directory was created or not.

Comment: Also note that from android 6 you have to manually accept the permission from the 'app info' screen. (Not sure if this is applicable what version of android are you testing this on?)

Comment: Sine Android 6.0 you have to add code to ask the user for runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime permissions is the answer, thanks.